# Vb6 doens't compile- generates huge tmp files

Tags: vb6, windows-7-x64, ocx

One of the vb6 project which worked fine in XP machine is not working on Windows 7 64 bit.

When I tried compiling the vb6 project on win7 machine it compiles forever and generates enormous .tmp files.

Update #1: When I tried building the exe using command prompt it worked.Not sure why it happens when I build from VB6 IDE

Update #2: Tried all the alternates like running application in administrator privileges,registered dlls in SYSWOW, etc.

Update #3: When I started with a fresh copy of the application I get mscomctl.ocx could not be loaded error.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: does it run with Ctrl+F5 (start with full compile)

Comment: I have projects that compile happily on Win 7  - 64 bit

Comment: I have been working with VB6 on Win7 for three years, with no problems. What kind of projects are we talking about? How many modules/classes? Unless you give more information, then this will have to be closed.

Comment: @Rob Yes I do have some other applications that are running fine in windows 7.This is the problematic one.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw It is a small application with 30 odd forms and 5 components (ocx)

Comment: @Rob Running with ctrl+F5 doesn't work for me

Comment: It is possible it could be one of the components at fault. Try creating a new EXE, add a component, press CTL-F5, and see if it fails. Repeat for each component. Oh, and delete all the .tmp files.

Comment: I created a new blank project with all the components used but it compiles fine.

Comment: components and references?

Comment: @Rob Yes, All components and references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue,

There appears to be conflict in DSR files on the project.After removing the dsr files in the project I can able to compile the project.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect permission issues. Download the excellent SysInternals `NTFILMON` utility to see where exactly it fails to process files. Set the filter to only show the processes that belong to VB6.

Comment: NTFILMON utility available for download?

Comment: Google ntfilmon, click the first link, click the first blue line that says ntfilmon 78kb.